# Justify that |x| + |y| = 1 is contained within the unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, proof-writing

I am working through Daepp and Gorkin's Reading Writing and Proving and came across a problem in chapter 6 that has me stumped. Specifically the question is this:

If $ A = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 \le 1 \}$ and $B = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| + |y| \le 1 \}$ is B properly contained in A?

So far I have had a few ideas. The first is to show that they are bounded on the same interval. I came to the conclusion after graphing each of A and B in desmos but am having a tough time formally proving this. The next is to show that the area of B is less than the area of A and so this implies that B is contained in A.

For the boundary conditions, if I let y = 0 in each case then I can show that $x \in B \implies x \in A$ and by symmetry, this would work for y as well. But this doesnt feel satisfying to me.. it feels short somehow.

The 'area' portion I have pretty much settled but am wondering if this is sufficient.

Any help with specifically drilling down a road map for the boundary conditions would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a correct proof of the whole matter: let $(x,y)\in B$ be arbitrary, then $(|x|+|y|)^2\le1$ by squaring both (nonnegative) sides of the defining equation, and
$$1\ge(|x|+|y|)^2\ge|x|^2+|y|^2=x^2+y^2$$
So $(x,y)\in A$ and $B\subseteq A$. To prove strict inclusion check that $(0.7,0.7)$ is in $A$ but not $B$.

Comment: This is very interesting and thank you so much for showing it! I am surprised however that you say x^2 + y^2 < |x| +|y| < 1 implies B is a subset of A. To me this shows the reverse. But I must be missing something?

Comment: @KeithRoberts I started with an element of $B$. Then I showed it is also in $A$. Hence $A$ _contains_ $B$, not the other way round.

Comment: You are making it to complicated. $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq (|x|+|y|)^{2}$ so $ B \subseteq A$ is pretty  obvious.

Comment: @geetha290krm please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

if $|x|+|y|\le 1$, both $|x|\le1 $ and $|y|\le 1$ are true, which implies $|x|^2\le |x|$ and $|y|^2\le |y|$. So
$$|x|^2 + |y|^2\le |x|+|y|\le 1$$

(**Edit:** This proof has the disadvantage that it does not work if you replace the assumption $|x|+|y|\le 1$ with the more general one that $|x|+|y|\le r$ for some $r>0$, while the claim remains true. But since both $||(x,y)||_1 := |x| + |y|$ and $||(x,y)||_2 := \sqrt{|x|^2 + |y|^2} $ are norms the general case follows by scaling).